# Passing a dynamic href into Fancybox Iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to build a href on the fly to pass it into fancybox iframe and pass the link into a php file

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a').each(function(){
    var Href = 'GetImg.php?img=' + $(this).attr("href");
    alert ("Href");
    $(".Images").click(function() {

           $.fancybox.open({
           href : Href,
           type : 'iframe',
           padding : 5
           });
    });
   };

 }) ; // ready
</script>
```

Href is being set ie alert ("Href") and passed into the php file but isn't opening in the  iframe.
if i hard code

```
href : 'GetImg.php?img=/images/myImg.jpg' it works
```

my link is

```
<a class="Images" href="/images/myImg.jpg" title="A witty Title">Send to PHP</a>
```

FYI This is the GetImg.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>Holly Gibbons</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox-2.0.6/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ddpowerzoomer.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('#image3').addpowerzoom({
        defaultpower: 2,
        powerrange: [2,5],
        largeimage: null,
        magnifiersize: [100,100] //<--no comma following last option!  
    }); 
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php 
  $my_img = $_GET['img'];
  ?>
<p> <img id="image3" src = <?php echo $my_img ?> /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the selector `$('a > img')`? The `img` tag doesn't seems to be there(within the `a` tag).

Comment: And `alert ("Href");` is just prints the string `Href`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to select all `a` tags and loop, you can do simply like

```
$(document).on('click', '.Images', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var Href = 'GetImg.php?img=' + $(this).attr("href");
    alert(Href);
    $.fancybox.open({
        href: Href,
        type: 'iframe',
        padding: 5
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanx that worked! now i need to workout how to re-size the iframe based on content.